# Calculate summation of (2n-1) using recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I need to calculate this summation both iteratively and recursively, I already did the iterative method and it is working fine. But I can't figure out how to do the recursive one.

The summation would go like this: 1 + 3 + 5 + 9 + ... + 2n −1

This is the iterative one:

```
    public int dIt(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i = 2 * i - 1) {
        if (i <= 1) {
            sum += i;
            i = 2;
        } else {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Is it possible to do it without carrying a counter on each recursive call? That is, only using n. I assume it would have to go backwards, from n to 0, but I don't know how to do that.

I know I don't have any code for this method yet, but I'm not asking for that, I would like some help as to how to think about the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but is your homework; so what do you expect us to tell you besides "this is how you do recursion in general" (and that is something you could easily research yourself)? The **learning part** is to think ... how on earth do I do this? When you go the "easy detour" and avoid that part ... what is left for you to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define:

1) case base:

```
  if(n==1) return 1
```

2) step:

```
  else return (doIt(n-1)) + (2*n-1)
```

Comment: Hi, thans for the answer! However, I'm getting different results when using the iterative and reccursive methods. For example, if I run it for n = 20, the Iterative method returns 35, while the Recursive one returns 400. I think the correct one is the Iterative, since the summation would be: 1 + 3 + 5 + 9 + 17 = 35. What do you think is the problem? Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. I think that your Iterative method is wrong.
For n=20 the result will be:
39 + 37 + 35 + 33 + 31 + ... + 1 = 400
In iterative method, your for could be: for(int i =0; i<n; i++)...

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking so long to reply, been very busy with school. With the iterative the summation would be 1 + 3 + 5 + 9 + 17 =35. It's not the summation of odd numbers, it (2n - 1). I think the recursive you posted is doing the summation of odd numbers. Or maybe I'm not understanding the exercise correctly. Again, thanks for helping me!

Answer (score -1):

```
public int doIt(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 2 * n - 1 + doIt(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: 1. Pure code answers are bad 2. OP specifically said he doesn't want complete code